# How to Make an UIButton Shrink Into an UIActivityIndicator When Pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to create an UIButton that will shrink down to an Activity Indicator when tapped on. The UIButton I'm referring to is named Request Ride. I have most of the code already set, but for some reason the button won't shrink and the indicator won't show up? I'll attach pictures of the app and my code.

// My app

[image]

[image]

// My end result I'm needing

[image]

// Main Storyboard

[image]

// HomeVC

```
@IBAction func actionBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        actionBtn.animateButton(shouldLoad: true, withMessage: nil)
    }
```

// RoundedShadowButton

```
class RoundedShadowButton: UIButton {

    // Variables
    var originalSize: CGRect?

    func setupView() {
        originalSize = self.frame
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        setupView()
    }

    func animateButton(shouldLoad: Bool, withMessage message: String?) {

        let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        spinner.style = .large
        spinner.color = UIColor.darkGray
        spinner.alpha = 0.0
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
        spinner.tag = 21

        if shouldLoad {
            self.addSubview(spinner)
            self.setTitle("", for: .normal)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
                self.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.midX - (self.frame.height / 2), y: self.frame.origin.y, width: self.frame.height, height: self.frame.height)
            }) { (finished) in
                if finished == true {
                    spinner.startAnimating()
                    spinner.center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width / 2 + 1, y: self.bounds.width / 2 + 1)
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                        spinner.alpha = 1.0
                    }
                }
            }
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        } else {
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            for subview in self.subviews {
                if subview.tag == 21 {
                    subview.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
                self.frame = self.originalSize!
                self.setTitle(message, for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code instead of image.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I edited the post to add my code :)

Answer (score 0):

One obvious thing is that this line is totally wrong:

```
spinner.center = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 + 1, y: self.frame.width / 2 + 1)
```

You are placing the spinner incorrectly. If the activity view is a subview of the button, then it needs to be centered at the middle of the button’s *bounds*, not its frame.

I was able to get an effect somewhat like what you are describing:

[image]

So this ought to be possible if you get your values right.

Comment: How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: I understand, but this is my first time doing an Activity Indicator programmatically

Comment: Added "screencast" showing that one can probably do the sort of thing you're after.

Comment: K I added my bounds to the spinner center, what do I need to fix next?